# How to force characters to be in a certain Upper or lower case sensitive format?

Tags: php

I have a simple search bar for a user to search any name in a database.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

And so whenever a user inputs the name I output

```
<h1> You have searched <?php print( "$name" )?>'s name</h1>
```

What I need is that for example if a user types, "leOnARD" for some reason, I would like it to come out as "Leonard" rather than "leOnARD".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ucfirst()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) with [`strtolower()`](https://www.php.net/strtolower) seems to be what you are looking for.

```
echo ucfirst(strtolower("leOnARD")); // prints Leonard
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ucfirst()` function in PHP. It will capitalize the first letter of your word.

Answer (score 0):

`ucfirst(strtolower($name));`

That will lower everything but the first letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<h1> You have searched <?php print ucfirst(strtolower( "$name" )) ?>'s name</h1>
```